# FOR LOOP Statement in BigQuery

Tags: for-loop, google-bigquery

I have data in two tables:

Table **activity**:

```
User_ID       Event_Time       Cmd

AMsySZb9GPcL  1512125190721078  1
AMsySZYQ-lAI  1512118629594674  0
AMsySZZMlPzD  1512125736366076  1
....
```

Table **behaviour**:

```
User_ID       Event_Time       

AMsySZZFezm   1512145788526664
AMsySZb9GPcL  1512125190721078
AMsySZY5YcTa  1512143509733637
AMsySZYQ-lAI  1512118629594674
AMsySZZMlPzD  1512125736366076
....
```

User_ID is type STRING, Event_Time is type INTEGER.

Step 1: The basic SELECT statement I am making now is:

```
SELECT activity.User_ID, activity.Event_Time FROM activity WHERE Cmd=1
```

Step 2: Then I would like to get data from **behaviour** table, but only for Users from Step 1 and only where behaviour.Event_Time is before activity.Event_Time.

For example: 
From Step 1 I got User_ID='AMsySZb9GPcL' and I need:

```
SELECT behaviour.User_ID, behaviour.Event_Time
FROM behaviour 
WHERE User_ID='AMsySZb9GPcL' AND activity.Event_Time >= behaviour.Event_Time
```

But the problem is that I have to do the same for every User_ID from Step 1, I am not sure if it is the supported functionality of SQL, but I need something like FOR LOOP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need FOR LOOP for this - you should think of set based operation when you deal with SQL of any sort - so you can process all your users in one shot using power of [`JOIN`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#join-types)s

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  activity.User_ID User_ID, 
  activity.Event_Time activity_Time, 
  behaviour.Event_Time behaviour_Time
FROM `project.dataset.activity` activity
JOIN `project.dataset.behaviour` behaviour 
ON activity.User_ID = behaviour.User_ID
AND activity.Event_Time >= behaviour.Event_Time
WHERE Cmd = 1
```

You can test / play with above using dummy data from your example:

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.activity` AS (
  SELECT 'AMsySZb9GPcL' User_ID, 1512125190721078 Event_Time, 1 Cmd UNION ALL
  SELECT 'AMsySZYQ-lAI', 1512118629594674, 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'AMsySZZMlPzD', 1512125736366076, 1 
), `project.dataset.behaviour` AS (
  SELECT 'AMsySZZFezm ' User_ID, 1512145788526664 Event_Time UNION ALL
  SELECT 'AMsySZb9GPcL', 1512125190721078 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'AMsySZY5YcTa', 1512143509733637 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'AMsySZYQ-lAI', 1512118629594674 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'AMsySZZMlPzD', 1512125736366076 
)
SELECT 
  activity.User_ID User_ID, 
  activity.Event_Time activity_Time, 
  behaviour.Event_Time behaviour_Time
FROM `project.dataset.activity` activity
JOIN `project.dataset.behaviour` behaviour 
ON activity.User_ID = behaviour.User_ID
AND activity.Event_Time >= behaviour.Event_Time
WHERE Cmd=1
```